# Как сделать пополнение текста в js?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть таблицы, в одну вводиться отзыв и при отправке он выводиться на вторую. Но не могу понять как сделать так чтобы каждая отправка отзыва сохранялась во второй таблице. Код выглядит вот так:

[image: Мой код]

```
<script>

    if(localStorage.getItem('textarea2'))
        textarea2.value = localStorage.getItem('textarea2');
    send.addEventListener('click',()=> {
        textarea2.value = textarea1.value;
        localStorage.setItem('textarea2', textarea2.value);

    });

</script>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите, чтоб информация не затиралась, то надо не присваивать новое значение, а добавлять до уже существующего (+=)

```
<script>

    if(localStorage.getItem('textarea2'))
        textarea2.value = localStorage.getItem('textarea2');
    send.addEventListener('click',()=> {
        textarea2.value += textarea1.value; // вот здесь
        localStorage.setItem('textarea2', textarea2.value);

    });
```

Правильно заметили, что если нужно с новой строки, то:

```
 textarea2.value += textarea1.value + '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно каждое значение textarea1 вписывать с новой строки.

```
<textarea rows="7" cols="45" id="textarea1" placeholder="Введите отзыв"></textarea>
<br><br>
<button id="send">Отправить отзыв</button>
<br><br>
<textarea rows="7" cols="45" id="textarea2" placeholder="Ваш отзыв будет тут"></textarea>
<script>
    if(localStorage.getItem('textarea2'))
        textarea2.value = localStorage.getItem('textarea2');
    send.addEventListener('click',()=> {
        textarea2.value = textarea2.value + '\n' + textarea1.value;
        localStorage.setItem('textarea2', textarea2.value);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось, так как и хотел:) Добра всем